# ping monitoring tool excel

Tags: excel, vba, networking, ping

i already have ping tool in ms excel and it is working fine.. but i want to add time delay of  10 sec for every next ip ping. If required i am adding code here. Thanks in advance.

```
    Function Ping(strip)
      Dim objshell, boolcode
      Set objshell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
      boolcode = objshell.Run("ping -n 1 -w 1000 " & strip, 0, True)
      If boolcode = 0 Then
          Ping = True
      Else
          Ping = False
      End If
    End Function
    Sub PingSystem()
      Dim strip As String
      Do Until Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "STOP"
        Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "TESTING"
        For introw = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(65536, 2).End(xlUp).Row
          strip = ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 2).Value
          If Ping(strip) = True Then
             ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
             ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
             ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Value = "Online"
             Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
             ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Font.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
          Else
             ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
             ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Font.Color = RGB(200, 0, 0)
             ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Value = "Offline"
             Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
             ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
         End If
         If Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "STOP" Then
            Exit For
         End If
        Next
      Loop
      Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "IDLE"
    End Sub
    
    Sub stop_ping()
        Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "STOP"
    End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")`